# Different Hubspot forms for different posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The site has a call to action area. The call to action area needs to have different title, description and form for different posts. The forms are created using Hubspot. How can I have a different call to action for different post? I though of using advanced custom fields but how do I have a different title and description for every post?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Custom Fields would be a great solution to this. You'd create a field group with "title", "description", and "hubspot_embed_code" or something similar, and apply that field group to all posts.

Then when editing a post, you'd be able to specify those three fields, uniquely for each post. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, ACF would probably be the perfect way to go for this problem.